Please help me identify this connector/plug (Nautilus acoustic guitar pickup)
I have a piezo pickup system in my acoustic guitar. The brand name is "Nautilus".

Clumsy as I am, I managed to break some tiny leads off the plug that goes into the volume control.

I don't think I can solder this back together and even if I can, I think the connection will not be very sturdy. I might be better off replacing the whole plug.
Can anyone tell me the name of this plug or a place where I could order such a plug?
Here is another picture of male part with a picture of the part this plug goes into.

Do you have another idea how I could fix this defective connection?
Update 1:
Here are two more pictures of the plug.


Update 2: I opened up the volume control and managed to take another and better picture of the female part.

Update 3:The side length is slightly below 2.54mm. I also tried to fit header pins into the plug, but they are to big.

Luckily there are no electronics underneath the shrinkwrap.


you're showing the less interesting sides of the plug: please show us its front. You also might want to peruse Davide's excellent connector identifcation tool.

Thanks, I will try the identification tool ... looks promising. I also uploaded two more pictures ...

@Marcus Müller - Thak you for the kudos. Unfortunately, my Identiconn does not list OP"s connector. It may be custom.

@Special.Guest by the way, to say something nice: this doesn't look like it was your clumsiness. To me, it looks like these metal parts were weakened by regular movement, i.e., material fatigue, before the remaining mechanical connection was so thin it could break like this. Probably a bit of an underdimensioned choice of a connector for something attached to a musician!

but seeing the matching "male" side of the connector: can you measure the distance between these pins? If they are on a square with side length 2.54mm, you might be able to just use a female "pin header" with 2×2 contacts, but would then need to take care to plug things in in the correct orientation. (and you'd have to add appropriate strain relief, maybe just a generous amount of epoxy glue or something, so that this won't happen again). But first, you would carefully "scalpell off" the rubbery shrinkwrap around the "stem" of the broken-off connector, to make sure there's no electronics…

… hidden in there that you need to safe

@Marcus Müller maybe I should just think of it as 'natural wear and tear from virtuoso performance'. I added two more pictures. I don't think I can fix this with a 2,54mm Pin header ... luckily there are no electronics underneath the shrinkwrap

@Special.Guest yes, see its failure as tribute to art :-D If vir's answer doesn't fit, you could try to find non-standard pin headers (they exist with spacings other than 2.54 mm, but they're rarer.)

It appears to be a Hirose DF11-4DS-2C. Although Digikey's "360° view" is preventing me from verifying the "Y" and "A" markings on the side.

That's it! Thank you so much! You're a legend!

vir, if it helps, Hirose's IGES 3D model doesn't have the markings, either.

@Special.Guest don't thank me until you see how much the tooling costs.

@Special.Guest Note that you typically need to buy the plastic housing of the connector, and the contacts, as separate parts

@vir yeah, I think it would probably be a good idea to try and find a company that provides crimping as an offering (Or. hm. buy 20 contacts instead of the 4 someone with good tools would need, and have a few curses over tea, pliers, and band-aid; would probably work, but be suboptimal)

I think those contacts would work well with the universal "Engineer" crimping tool but those are still about $100. Maybe set up a side gig fixing them for friends?

@TomCarpenter had an idea to solder the through-hole receptacle onto the board and sidestep the whole crimping process. Not sure why the comment was deleted though it sounds to me like it would be worth a try.

Uff, I hoped just any old crimping tool would do the job. But I guess the cheap ones aren't small enough.
@vir Is this the universal "Engineer" crimping tool you are talking about? https://www.amazon.de/Universal-Crimpzange-unterschiedlichen-Steckverbinderhersteller-ENGINEER-PA-20/dp/B002AVVO7U?source=ps-sl-shoppingads-lpcontext&ref_=fplfs&smid=AGWPWD8ERROFY&th=1

Yes, that is the one. I have not used it with those contacts though, so I cannot guarantee that it will provide an acceptable crimp.

@Special.Guest I've used that crimp tool. It takes some practice to get good at making reliable crimps, but after getting good at it it's worked well for all the things I've used for it. However, the manufacturer recommends using their PA-09 crimper for hirose DF11 contacts, not PA-20 (which is for slightly larger contacts).
